# Intersection of two array which contain exact reverse order of elements

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose, I have a two arrays and second array has reverse order of elements than first array (number of elements in both arrays could be different), then is there any way/method in python to find number of sets which are in both arrays but in reverse order.

For example,

```py
X = ['a','b','c','d'],
Y = ['a','b','d','c']
```

then, the result(intersection) must be 1 as, only `{'c','d'}` is the only set in both arrays and in reverse order.

Comment: number of elements? Then why not 2? Or do you mean number of set intersections?

Comment: @BlueRineS Yes, number of sets, sorry typing mistake edited, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set of 2 element pairs (using `zip(X, X[1:])`) and find the intersection of such 2 element pairs from Y (in reverse order, using `zip(Y[1:], Y)`)

```
>>> X = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> Y = ['a','b','d','c']
>>> res = set(zip(X, X[1:])).intersection(zip(Y[1:], Y))
>>> res
{('c', 'd')}
>>> len(res)
1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. If I have your 5 minutes may I know the exact feature of 'ZIP', better to know from you rather learn from internet. PS. I have just started to learn python, sorry in advance if it seems as a stupid question.

Comment: zip interleaves two lists. so `list(zip(['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3']))` would give you `[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]`

Comment: Perfect, and thank you very much for your precious time.